# What units does the Google Maps API's event.overlay.getRadius return value use?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geometry, spatial

I am using the below code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function(event) {
   if(event.type == 'circle') {
      $('#radius').val(event.overlay.getRadius());
   }
}
```

What is the measurement unit of this radius?

Comment: In this case the `event.overlay` is a `Circle` and `getRadius` "Returns the radius of this circle (in meters).".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meters [according to documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Circle.getRadius)